# Permission to hit google API from a cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to get the Airflow URL and other information from Composer. For that I'm trying to use the Google API (`https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/COMPOSER_LOCATION/environments/COMPOSER_NAME'`). This is the code that I use:

```py
import logging
import requests

import google.cloud.logging
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

client = google.cloud.logging.Client(project="project ID of the Cloud Function")
client.setup_logging()

AUTH_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
CREDENTIALS, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=[AUTH_SCOPE])


def request_api(url: str, method: str) -> dict:
    authed_session = AuthorizedSession(CREDENTIALS)
    response = authed_session.request(method, url)

    if response.status_code == 403:
        raise requests.HTTPError(
            "You do not have a permission to perform this operation. "
            "Check Airflow RBAC roles for your account."
            f"{response.headers} / {response.text}"
        )
    elif response.status_code != 200:
        response.raise_for_status()
    else:
        return response.json()


def main():
    project_id = 'some project ID'
    location = 'some location'
    composer_name = 'some composer name'
    request_url = (
        'https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/'
        f'projects/{project_id}/'
        f'locations/{location}/'
        f'environments/{composer_name}'
    )

    response = request_api(request_url, 'GET')
    logging.info(f"Response from API: {response}")
```

But when I run it I got an HTTP 403 error.

```
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The caller does not have permission", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }
```

In this case the caller is the service account that run the Cloud Function, right? So what permissions must have the service account that run the cloud function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control#permissions

Comment: Could you give me more guidance instead of send me to "RTFM"?

Comment: What you call guidance I can interpret it as "I don't want to read just give me the answer". Have you read the doc? Have you seen the different roles? For example did you check the `Composer User` role? The reason I commented to check the doc is because there are multiple roles that can grant the permission but depending on how far you may want to interact with your service you can choose a different one or even create a custom one

Comment: I try a lot of them, but I cannot find which is the right one for use the Google API. For example another step that i omitted in the snippet is consume the Airflow API y for that I use "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken", but for https://composer.googleapis.com/v1beta1/blahblahblah I had struggle a lot and for that I post this question.

Sorry if I sounded hostile, but as I told you I have tried several permissions and every time I have to be bothering an external team in my work :(

Comment: You can also follow this [quickstart documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/run-apache-airflow-dag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Puteri comment. My cloud function can consume the Composer API if their service account have the role [Composer User (roles/composer.user)](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control#composer.user).